# extension method overriding inherited method

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

in the following code I define an interface, an abstract base class with a method that prints "foo", a class that implements both, and an extension method on the interface with a signature equal to a method in the abstract base class that prints "bar". when I run this sample, why is "bar" printed instead of "foo"? and if applicable, what's the morale behind this language design choice?

```
public interface ISomething
{}

public abstract class SomethingElse
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo");
    }
}

public class DefinitelySomething : SomethingElse, ISomething
{}

public static class ISomethingExtensions
{
    public static void foo(this ISomething graphic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bar");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISomething g = new DefinitelySomething();
        g.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the variable is declared as `ISomething`.

The instance method is not known until run-time however the method overload resolution is at compile time. There's no guarantee that the instance actually has a suitable method. In you particular example it has but that's from a type safety perspective an irrelevant coincidence. The important type at the line `g.foo()` is the type that g is *declared* as not the run time type

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because to me it is the most comprehensible answer that explains the rationale behind inheritance and extension methods in this question.

Answer (score 9):

`ISomething` does not have a member called `foo`, so the extension method will be called.

Answer (score 1):

The `foo` method on `SomethingElse` is not considered for overload resolution as you are acting on an instance of `ISomething`.

Or to think about it another way, consider what would happen if you didn't have any extension method? In this case you would get a compile error as no other suitable method could be found.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
DefinitelySomething g = new DefinitelySomething();
g.foo();
```

And it should behave how you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you call the `foo` method of the `ISomething`, and it is resolved into extension method.

If you use this code:

```
ISomething g = new DefinitelySomething();
(g as SomethingElse).foo();
```

you'll get the right output.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check inside the extension method to see if the object you are currently using has an existing method with the exact same signature

```
    public static System.Reflection.MethodInfo ExtensionOverrider(this Object obj, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method )
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetMethods().Where(
            x => x.Name == method.Name &&
            x.GetParameters().Select(z => z.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(method.GetParameters().Skip(1).Select(w => w.ParameterType))).FirstOrDefault(); 
    }


    public static void foo(this ISomething graphic)
    {
        var Method = graphic.ExtensionOverrider(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());                
        if( Method != null)
            Method.Invoke(graphic, new Object[0]{});
        else
            Console.WriteLine("bar");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just some more examples, tested in LinqPad.
Note that the items declared as `ISomething` use the extension method and return *"bar"*, which as @leppie [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307023/1037948) is because `ISomething` does not have a method `foo`, but calling `foo` on the new instance directly gives the correct output *"foo"*.

```
void Main(string[] args) {
        // baseline
        var g0 = new DefinitelyNothing();                   g0.foo(); // "foo"

        ISomething g;

        // won't work, not ISomething
        // g = new DefinitelyNothing();     g.foo();

        g = new DefinitelyNothingThatThinksItsSomething();  g.foo(); // "bar"
            new DefinitelyNothingThatThinksItsSomething().foo();    // "foo"

        g = new DefinitelySomething();                      g.foo(); // "bar"
            new DefinitelySomething().foo();                        // "foo"

        g = new DefinitelySomethingWithFoo();               g.foo(); // "bar"
            new DefinitelySomethingWithFoo().foo();                 // "foo"
            (g as IWithFoo).foo();                                  // "foo", not "qux"

        g = new DefinitelySomethingFromNothingWithFoo();    g.foo(); // "bar"
            new DefinitelySomethingFromNothingWithFoo().foo();      // "foo"
            (g as ISomethingWithFoo).foo();                         // "foo", not "baz"

        IWithFoo g1;
        g1 = new DefinitelyNothingWithFoo();                g1.foo(); // "foo"
            new DefinitelyNothingWithFoo().foo();                    // "foo"
}

public interface ISomething {}
public interface IWithFoo {
    void foo();
}
public interface ISomethingWithFoo : ISomething, IWithFoo {}

public abstract class Nothing {
    public void foo() { Console.WriteLine("foo"); }
}
public abstract class NothingWithFoo : IWithFoo {
    public void foo() { Console.WriteLine("foo"); }
}
public abstract class Something : ISomething {
    public void foo() { Console.WriteLine("foo"); }
}
public abstract class SomethingWithFoo : ISomethingWithFoo {
    public void foo() { Console.WriteLine("foo"); }
}
public abstract class SomethingFromNothingWithFoo : Nothing, ISomethingWithFoo {}

public class DefinitelyNothing: Nothing {}
public class DefinitelyNothingThatThinksItsSomething: Nothing, ISomething {}
public class DefinitelyNothingWithFoo : NothingWithFoo {}

public class DefinitelySomething : Something {}
public class DefinitelySomethingWithFoo : SomethingWithFoo {}
public class DefinitelySomethingFromNothingWithFoo : SomethingFromNothingWithFoo {}


public static class ISomethingExtensions {
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable
    public static void foo(this ISomething whatever) { Console.WriteLine("bar"); }
    public static void foo(this ISomethingWithFoo whatever) { Console.WriteLine("baz"); }
    public static void foo(this IWithFoo whatever) { Console.WriteLine("qux"); }
}
```